# How does an :as association work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, metaprogramming

My comments model is pretty simple and works polymorphically, but I am now adding the ability to hide a comment by the author of a given record across those polymorphic associations.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :show
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So, requests, questions, posts, submissions etc... all have comments and are accessing the comments template without issue, but I want to allow the author of the content in those models to show or hide comments (as opposed to flagging, for example) when the application identifies them as the author of the content that is being commented on.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

So, I have everything working when there is only one model, by calling the author: @request.user,
but I'm wondering how to call an author using metaprogramming, so the comment view (with help) can determine what model is currently using the comment view.

I've done some research into metaprogramming, but have not found the answer.

Here is the code that calls the author (@request.user):

```
    <% if @comments %>
        <h1 class="mtop20">Comments</h1>
        <% for comment in @comments %>
           <% if signed_in? %>
                <% if comment.show == true %>
                   <div class="well comment mtop10">
                        <% if current_user == @request.user or current_user.has_role? :admin %>
                             <%= simple_form_for [@commentable, comment] do |f| %>
                              <div class ="">
                                <%= f.input :show, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => false }  %>
                                <%= f.submit "Hide Comment", :class => 'btn btn-mini pull-right' %>
                              </div>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        <span>
                           <%= image_tag comment.user.image.source(:header) %>
                           <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %></span>
                           Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
                        </span>
                        <p class="mleft20 mtop10"><%= comment.content %></p>
                        <% if signed_in? %>
                            <% if current_user.id == comment.user_id or current_user.has_role? :admin %>
                                <%= link_to 'Edit', polymorphic_path([ comment.commentable, comment], :action => :edit), 
                                                    :class => 'btn btn-mini mtop5 mleft10' %>
                                <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.commentable, comment],
                                                    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                                    method: :delete, 
                                                    :class => 'btn btn-mini mtop5' %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                   </div>
               <% end %>
               <% if comment.show == false %>
                  <p>A comment by <%= comment.user.name %> has been hidden by <%= @request.user.name %></p>
                  <% if current_user == @request.user or current_user.has_role? :admin %>
                     <%= simple_form_for [@commentable, comment] do |f| %>
                      <div class ="">
                        <%= f.input :show, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => true }  %>
                        <%= f.submit "Show Comment", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
               <% end %>
          <% end %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
```

Comment: "I am now adding the ability to hide a comment by the author of a given record" - what do you mean by this? hide all comments submitted by a particular user? also, what is @request?

Comment: @MikeCampbell have added more background information in the original question to clarify.

Comment: i'm trying hard, but... what do you mean ? what is the question ? can't you just do `comment.commentable.user` ?

Comment: @m_x it's not the comment user that I want to allow to hide the comment, it's the author of the content that is being commented on. Say author creates post and commenter comments on the post. I want author of post to be able to hide the comment, not the commenter. Are you saying that comment.commentable.user will call the author of the post?

Comment: @m_x I'm getting an error on one of the polymorphic associations because it's a nested route, unlike the others. So, you answered the original question and would be happy to give you credit for that if you'd like to post. The problem has now evolved into a new question which I'll do my best to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `comment.commentable.user` to access the author of your post.